# Scroll down a scroll bar from a div c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of the div.
Here is a code from python which is working.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginated') #this one is the div
if len(element) > 0:
     driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', element[0])
```

Does anyone know how to convert it for C#? I saw that I don't have `execute_script` in C#

Comment: IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight"); Hopefully this will help.

Comment: https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same code, in C# would be:

```
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("paginated"));
if (elements.Any())
{
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver)
        .ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight",
            elements.First());
}
```